# How to enable block "overlay" with a gear

Tags: 7

How to enable the gear in the top-right corner of a block in Drupal 7 as shown in the screenshot below?

[image]

I have several Drupal 7 installations with Bartik theme and only one of them has it and I can not find, where to enable it for the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to turn on the core Contextual Links module, and make sure that all roles that should be able to see those links have the "Use contextual links" permission.

If it's still not showing, check to see if your theme has a custom block.tpl.php file. If so, make sure that the `$title_prefix` and `$title_suffix` variables are being printed out (see the [original template file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7)).

The contextual links output is contained in one of those vars (I think it's `$title_suffix` actually) so the links won't be printed unless the correct one of those vars is also printed.